# How to count distribution in numbers and percent of binary column in table?

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql, enterprise-guide, 4gl

i have table in SAS Enterprise Guide like below:

**Below table DOES NOT have duplicates in ID column.**

```
ID  | TARGET 
----|--------
123 | 0
456 | 0 
777 | 1 
889 | 0 
122 | 1
```

And I would like to aggregate above table with sample data (original table has many more data) to have something like below:

- Q_0 - number of ID with '0' in column TARGET
- Q_1 - number of ID with '1' in column TARGET
- P_0 - prcent of ID with '0' in column TARGET
- P_1 - prcent of ID with '1' in column TARGET

  | Q_0 | Q_1 | P_0 | P_1 | COL1 |
  | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
  | 3 | 2 | 0.6 | 0.4 | XXX |

How can I do that in SAS Enterprise Guide in normal SAS or in PROC SQL ?

Comment: Can you post a small representable sample of the sample data?

Comment: Peter, I edited my post, to better present problem and I add new column also :) is ok now for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PROC FREQ gives you the data but not in the desired format.

```
proc freq data=have;
table target /out=want outpct;
run;
```

If you really want that format, SQL is probably the easiest though the most manual. If you have missing values this probably needs to be adjusted.

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select sum(target=1) as q_1,
       sum(taget=0) as q_0, 
       mean(target) as p_1 format=percent12.1,
       1-mean(target) as p_0 format=percent12.1
from have;
quit;
```